# .htaccess - removing .html file extension causes 500 internal error (for what should be 404?)

Tags: .htaccess, url, internal-server-error, errordocument

Im using .htaccess to remove the .html extension from my urls. For example...

> https://www.example.com/work.html > https://www.example.com/work

I want to be able to have the site show a 404 page (or the correct error page) if someone tries to access a file/directory thats not there (for example) https://www.example.com/work/new. But this returns a 500 Internal Server Error.

The .htaccess line **ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html** doesn't return that file (it works for 404, 403 etc). It returns this error...

> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache error log says...

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due     to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I am assuming that this is due to it essentially trying to find a directory within a html file (trying to find directory "new" inside the html file "work.html"), so returns the 500 server error rather than 404.

Below is my .htaccess file. Can anyone help with a better way of doing this or a way around it?

```
# Disable Directory Listing
Options -Indexes

# X-Robots-Tag
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"

# Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Root Directory
RewriteBase /

# Remove .html Extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]

# Remove index + Reference Directory
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# Remove Trailing Slash **If Not Directory**
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# Forward Request To html File, **But Don't Redirect (Bot Friendly)**
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]

# Errors
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
```

Comment: Check your Apache `error.log` file for reasons of 500 error.

Comment: Apache error log says... “AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.”

Comment: Is `https://www.example.com/work` causing 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]
> ```

You need `L` (`last`) flags on *all* your *external redirects* in order to prevent further processing. For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, make sure `MultiViews` is disabled:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
```

Presumably, you are already linking to the URL *without* the extension?

Comment: thanks for the response. I've added your suggestions. All external redirects now have L flags and I've also disabled MultiViews. Still getting the same  AH00124 error.

Comment: Also, yes I am linking to the URL without the extension